# MySQL - Realizar consulta cada X filas

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito hacer diferentes consultas en una base de datos y, en vez de recibir todos los datos, necesito que cada X datos (filas) se haga una media. Por ejemplo:

Si ejecuto la siguiente query:

```
select H_TIERRA from parametros where fecha > '2022-06-10 10:00:00' and fecha < '2022-06-10 14:00:00';
```

Obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
+----------+
| H_TIERRA |
+----------+
|    86.80 |
|    86.72 |
|    86.63 |
|    86.55 |
|    86.47 |
|    86.39 |
|    86.30 |
|    86.22 |
|    86.14 |
|    86.06 |
|    85.97 |
|    85.89 |
|    85.81 |
|    85.73 |
|    85.65 |
|    85.57 |
|    85.48 |
|    85.40 |
|    85.32 |
|    85.24 |
|    85.16 |
|    85.08 |
|    85.00 |
|    84.92 |
|    84.84 |
|    84.76 |
|    84.68 |
|    84.60 |
|    84.52 |
|    84.44 |
|    84.36 |
|    84.28 |
|    84.21 |
|    84.13 |
|    84.05 |
|    83.97 |
|    83.89 |
|    83.81 |
|    83.74 |
|    83.66 |
|    83.58 |
|    83.50 |
|    83.43 |
|    83.35 |
|    83.27 |
|    83.19 |
|    83.12 |
+----------+
47 rows in set (0,01 sec)
```

Lo que necesito es obtener únicamente, por ejemplo, 10 filas de resultados haciendo una media cada  4,7 filas obtenidas de la query original.

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Es MySQL o es Oracle? Son productos distintos con sintaxis distinta.

Comment: Es en MySQL. Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido Stefan Aurelian Dumitrescu a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: ¿Estarías buscando una "media móvil"? ¿Qué significa 4, 7? ¿El orden de aparición lo determina la fecha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder hacer lo que deseas, necesitas poder agrupar tus filas de cierta forma. En este caso, lo que quieres es terminar con un determinado número de filas y para eso podemos utilizar `NTILE(n)`. Esa función dividirá las filas en grupos similares de acuerdo a un orden dado y les asignará un número de grupo a cada fila. Teniendo ese número de grupo, ya podemos obtener el promedio de cada grupo.

En este ejemplo, utilicé la fecha para ordenar, pero tal vez quieras ordenar de una forma distinta.

```
SELECT AVG( H_TIERRA) AS H_TIERRA
FROM ( SELECT H_TIERRA,
              NTILE( 10) OVER( ORDER BY fecha) AS grupo
       FROM parametros 
       WHERE fecha > '2022-06-10 10:00:00' AND fecha < '2022-06-10 14:00:00') AS q
GROUP BY grupo;
```

Dejo el ejemplo funcional con datos de prueba por si alguien lo quiere utilizar. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bhPnEfuTdnNJ4knLbZowPF/0

Comment: Muchas gracias Luis. Es justo lo que necesitaba!